# FluentValidation rule

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, fluentvalidation

I have a question regarding FluentValidation. I currently have the following validation:

```
  RuleFor(x => x.value)
       .NotNull()
       .WithMessage("This field is mandatory.");
```

How could I add a condition so that validation is only done when the value of the x.mandatory attribute is equal to true?

Answer (score 1):

FluentValidation supports conditions with the `When` and `Unless` methods. See this page in the docs for details https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html

You can achieve what you're after by chaining the call to `When` after NotNull:

```
 RuleFor(x => x.value)
   .NotNull()
   .When(x => x.mandatory)
   .WithMessage("This field is mandatory.");
```